# Do I need to specify entire schema to append data into an existing Google BigQuery table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an existing Google BigQuery table with about 30 fields. I would like to start automating the addition of data to this table on a regular basis. I have installed the command line tools and they are working correctly.

I'm confused by the proper process to append data to a table. Do I need to specify the entire schema for the table every time I want to append data? It feels strange to be recreating the schema in an avro file. The schema already exists on the table.

Can someone please clarify how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to specify the entire schema for the table every time

No, you don't need to do this. as described in BigQuery [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect)

> Schema auto-detection is not used with Avro files, Parquet files, ORC files, Cloud Firestore export files, or Cloud Datastore export files. When you load these files into BigQuery, **the table schema is automatically retrieved from the self-describing source data**.

Comment: I have tried that. However, I have a timestamp field in the table. When I try to upload data via JSON, I get an error that: `Field order.date has changed mode from REQUIRED to NULLABLE`. However, I am only trying to upload a single record as a test, and it does contain a value for `order.date`, so why is the load trying to alter the schema?

Comment: Oddly it worked using the CLI but not through the UI

Comment: Can you use the cli moving forward or this is an issue for you?

Comment: Yea I guess I can use the cli. It’s still odd there is an inconsistency. I’ll see if I can figure out why.

Comment: Cool, If My answer helped you in anyway please consider accepting/voting-up if appropiate. Thank you.